# one way and two way data binding in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

while building a very large scale angular application i came across a performance issue. all my components and views heavily depend on data bindings, there ng-repeats everywhere. so i decided to remove all the 2 way databindings by adding     `{{::scopevariableName}}`, now since there is no 2 way data binding my question is will the view update if modal value is changed in the controller?

```
function myCtr(){
   var that=this;
   this.scopevariableName='hannad'
   this.someFunction=function(){
     someEvent(function(callbackData){
        if(callbackData){
           that.scopevariableName='new value for scope variable'
       }
  });
 }
}


<p ng-bind="::$ctrl.somevariableName"></p>
```

Comment: Try to recompile your view manually.

Comment: @lin  what is the default behaviour or oneway bindings?

Comment: For a realy oneway binding, yes. The following link will may help you but its not a realy one-way-binding. This is an example for isolated scopes: https://jsfiddle.net/toddmotto/wauana12/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=wauana12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> from the docs: One-time expressions
>   will stop recalculating once they are stable, which happens after the
>   first digest if the expression result is a non-undefined value.

My understanding of one-time binding is after the first initialization of the scope variable if the object value changes the view will NOT change. 
because the watchers are not in effect.
ex

```
$scope.myVar=null;
<p>{{::myVar}}</p>
```

if the there are any changes to `$scope.myVar` those will not effect in the view
because it will take only its first initialization value. thats null.